# xfce compose key not working in xfce4-terminal

Tags: command-line, keyboard, xfce, xfce4-terminal, compose-key

I configured my compose key in `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
~ $ cat /etc/default/keyboard 
# Check /usr/share/doc/keyboard-configuration/README.Debian for
# documentation on what to do after having modified this file.

# The following variables describe your keyboard and can have the same
# values as the XkbModel, XkbLayout, XkbVariant and XkbOptions options
# in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="compose:lwin"
```

Now the compose key is working in all GUI apps (Chrome, Firefox, Notes, emacs etc). However its not working in xfce4-terminal and also any of its subprocesses. For example when I start emacs from the menu the compose key will work but if i start it from the terminal (and a new GUI window opens) the compose key fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `xfce4-terminal` is independent of the X server.  See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/194202/remapping-keys-system-wide-in-linux-not-just-in-x) on SuperUser, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu.